# encryption on AMIs for Cent OS?

Tags: linux, centos, cloud, amazon-web-services

We wanted use encrypted for 10GB partitions on AWS cloud using Cent OS i have following Cent OS following link to do that http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/EncryptedFilesystem

After attaching 10GB from us-east-1c
A:- dd if=/dev/urandom of=key bs=256 count=1
B:- cryptsetup -v -s 256 luksFormat /dev/sdb1 key

its do nothing from here after like i left for 24hr to finish task but it was on same

## WARNING!

This will overwrite data on /dev/sdb1 irrevocably.
Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES

any one face same type of issues if yes what is solutions for the same!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the easiest way to do encryption for partitions/drives on AWS is to use a third party management tool like [enstratus](http://www.enstratus.com/) which allows you to setup the encryption during the creation of the instance. You can either provide the AES256 encryption key or it can generate one for you.

Enstratus is chargeable on a monthly basis but the free account allows you to manage upto 5 machines without a cost.

Comment: we are looking same think open source!! thanks a ton with you suggestions